# MYSQL - Inner Join 3 Tables

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

1. Table of rule_of_exam 
   The field are id_rule, title_exam, id_class, id_subject, date_posting, id_teacher, info, status,time
2. Table of score_multichoice
   The field are id_score, id_rule, true, false, empty, score, id_student
3. Table of score_essay
   The field are id_scoressay, id_rule, id_student, score_essay

I joined them with the query

```
"Select * 
from rule_of_exam 
INNER JOIN score_multichoice ON rule_of_exam.id_rule = score_multichoice.id_rule 
WHERE id_student='$id_student'"
```

When I joined 2 tables it worked, but when I joined 3 tables it didn't work.

```
"Select * from rule_of_exam 
INNER JOIN score_multichoice ON rule_of_exam.id_rule = score_multichoice.id_rule
INNER JOIN score_essay ON rule_of_exam.id_rule = score_essay.id_rule
WHERE id_student='$id_student'"
```

The `$id_student` is from session student.

I expect the output

```
title_exam | score_essay | score
```

but it shows

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: what you get exactly in result (try var_dump($result) in php

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `id_student` occurs in more than one table: `score_multichoice` and `score_essay`. So the query doesn't know which one to pick. Change your query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM rule_of_exam 
INNER JOIN score_multichoice ON rule_of_exam.id_rule = score_multichoice.id_rule
INNER JOIN score_essay ON rule_of_exam.id_rule = score_essay.id_rule
WHERE score_essay.id_student = '$id_student'"
```

In other words: Tell MySQL specifically which table to use, and it could work. Make sure your PHP code can cope with zero result rows.

It would perhaps be better if `id_student` wasn't present in both table. Always [normalize your database](https://www.w3schools.in/dbms/database-normalization).

Comment: @NadyaF.W I've added `DISTINCT` to the select to select distinct results. This will only have an effect when there are true duplicates.